# Why are relays used in circuits when we have transistors?

Tags: transistors, relay

Why do I find relays being used right next to transistors? What is the benefit or use of using a relay over a transistor switch?

Comment: the switch contacts are isolated from the control signal

Comment: Low contact resistance.

Comment: And much higher volt/current models available.

Comment: Switching AC versus DC.

Comment: To the downvoters, downvoting duplicates as a "punishment" for not being able to find the duplicate is [AGAINST SE guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/should-we-downvote-duplicates), unless the OP has made an habit of posting duplicate questions. In itself the question is good, as it is demonstrated by the duplicates upvotes, and also better worded.

Comment: Thank you @LorenzoDonati but can you downvote me one more time so I can delete the question and earn a badge out of it? lol

Comment: To MichaelRader, to avoid this kind of downvotes in the future try to search the site well. When you post a question a list will come up with suggestions on possible duplicates. The duplicate of your question show up as the 5th of that list.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati the repeat question did not come up when I typed the questions. I always check this at least.

Comment: Note that duplicates are not bad in itself, so don't need to be removed. On the contrary they may help the search engine to find the topic.

Comment: Well this particular one needs to be deleted.

Comment: You are free to do so, of course, but keep in mind that if SE network didn't want duplicates, it would eliminate the feature altogether. The dupes feature is "by-design". This is also for downvoters.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati yes I will delete it after you downvote me one more please.

Comment: Sorry, but I won't downvote your question. This would be considered gaming the system. Moreover it could also lead (*rightfully*) to banning by the mods. This could also encourage people to post dupes on purpose. This kind of practices would defeat entirely the badge system. Your question is not bad and I ***won't*** downvote a good question just because it is a dupe or because you want to earn a badge. There are other legitimate ways to earn a badge.

Comment: Just saying its obviously being downvoted, might as well make it a positive thing.

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question. Give it time and the downnvotes may very well disappear altogether ;)